# Dynamic tables with formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, excel-tables

With office 365 (Excel) it's possible to create dynamic tables, similar to what Power Query does, by using spill formulas.

The advantage of dynamic tables over excel tables is that new rows and columns will automatically be created or removed.

Setting up these tables is a bit of a chore. Below is what I do. If anyone else has experimented with this, please give me some pointers.

Here is an example of a dynamic table without and with UDF's:

[image: Dynamic Table Without UDF Example][image: Dynamic Table With UDF Example]

In my example, there is the name of an existing excel table in `B1` and a column header name in `B2`. The dynamic table (and formula) starts in `A4`.
The formula for a dynamic table in A4. The table lists all unique values in an existing table `Table`'s, `Col` and provides a count. There is a totals row at the bottom. I also have dynamic formatting to make it look like an excel table.

Here is the Formula:

```
=LET(
    Table, B1,
    Col, B2,
    EmptyList, "-",
    Header, CHOOSE({1,2},"Name","Count"),

    MyColumn, INDIRECT(Table & "[" & Col & "]"),
    Uniques, UNIQUE(MyColumn),
    List, SORT(FILTER(Uniques,LEN(Uniques)>0,EmptyList),1,1),
    Counts, COUNTIF(MyColumn,"="&List),
    ReturnArray, IFERROR(CHOOSE({1,2},List, Counts),CHOOSE({1,2},EmptyList, EmptyList)),

    Totals, CHOOSE({1,2},"Total",IFERROR(SUM(Counts),EmptyList)),

    Range1,Header,
    Range2,ReturnArray,
    Range3,Totals,
    Rows1,ROWS(Range1),Rows2,ROWS(Range2),Rows3,ROWS(Range3),Cols1,COLUMNS(Range1),
    RowIndex,SEQUENCE(Rows1+Rows2+Rows3),ColIndex,SEQUENCE(1,Cols1),
    Range123,IF(RowIndex<=Rows1,INDEX(Range1,RowIndex,ColIndex),IF(RowIndex<=Rows1+Rows2,INDEX(Range2,RowIndex-Rows1,ColIndex),INDEX(Range3,RowIndex-Rows1-Rows2,ColIndex))),

    Return, Range123,
    Return
)
```

The formatting is done with 3 conditional formats applied to the entire sheet.

Header Format (font = bold, boarder = above and below):
`=AND(OR(ISERR(OFFSET(A1,-1,0)),ISBLANK(OFFSET(A1,-1,0)))=TRUE,ISBLANK(A1)=FALSE)`

Striping Format (color = gray):
`=AND(CELL("row",A1)=EVEN(CELL("row",A1)),ISBLANK(A1)=FALSE)`

Totals Format(font = bold, boarder = above and below):
`=AND(ISBLANK(A1)=FALSE,ISBLANK(A2)=TRUE)`

If the file is already macro-enabled, you can separate the dynamic table from other cells using the following UDF in your conditional formatting:

```
Function ListTables() As Variant
    
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Dim loTable As ListObject
    Dim aTables As Variant
    Dim lFound As Long
    
    lFound = 0
    ReDim aTables(1 To 1)
    
    For Each oSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each loTable In oSheet.ListObjects
            If Not loTable.HeaderRowRange Is Nothing Then
                ' This is a table
                lFound = lFound + 1
                ReDim Preserve aTables(1 To lFound)
                aTables(lFound) = loTable.Name
            End If
        Next loTable
    Next oSheet
    
    ListTables = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aTables)
End Function
```

I also use filters for my dynamic tables. I use support spill formulas with # reference to make dynamic drop-down boxes, then use a combination of `FILTER`, `UNIQUE`, and `SORT`.

Here is an example of what that looks like:

[image: Dynamic Dropdown List Filtering]

Here is the formula, this time with no headers or total row:

```
=LET(
    ColumnReturn,  Table_1[Column 1],
    TableFilter, E1,
    TableHeaderFilter, E2,
    ColumnFilter, INDIRECT(TableFilter & "[" & TableHeaderFilter & "]"),
    CriteriaExclude, E3,
    CriteriaOperator,E4,

    FilterEqual, FILTER(ColumnReturn,ColumnFilter = CriteriaExclude,"- None -"),
    FilterGreater, FILTER(ColumnReturn,ColumnFilter > CriteriaExclude,"- None -"),
    FilterLess,FILTER(ColumnReturn,ColumnFilter < CriteriaExclude,"- None -"),
    FilterNotEqual, FILTER(ColumnReturn,ColumnFilter<> CriteriaExclude,"- None -"),
    ListReturn, IF(CriteriaOperator = "=", FilterEqual, IF(CriteriaOperator = ">", FilterGreater, IF(CriteriaOperator = "<", FilterLess, IF(CriteriaOperator = "<>", FilterNotEqual, "")))),

    Return, IF(OR(ISBLANK(TableFilter),ISBLANK(TableHeaderFilter),ISBLANK(CriteriaExclude),ISBLANK(CriteriaOperator)),ColumnReturn,ListReturn),
    Return
)
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: @Dave Thunes I do not really see a question in here, can you narrow down "If anyone else has experimented with this, please give me some pointers"?

Comment: This statement is not quite clear to me: "The advantage of dynamic tables over excel tables is that new rows and columns will automatically be created or removed." By "automatically" do you mean instantaneously? As in, you do not need to click on Data > Refresh All, as you would have to if you were using Excel Tables with a Power Query solution? In any case, your solution seems to work fine and at a first glance, I don't see how to improve on it. A Power Query solution would certainly be a bit slower at refreshing the tables every time you change the filter selection.

Comment: I'm trying to make my spreadsheets more approachable for less tech-savvy co-workers. With the method above, others don't have to go data>refresh, or change the size of tables. Unfortunately, it's still to complicated for people to make changes to. Even if they're not scared away by the long formulas, they don't really understand them. For instance, I just fixed a table today that had 2 of the totals columns swapped.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Is there a way to make the formula more approachable? It's still too confusing for others to modify.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, this is a solution that instantly changes when data is changed, resizing as required. I think it's more user friendly to people who are used to old-fashioned excel. I use it to summarize databases, compare tables to each other, etc.